# Validation Class(dll)

Tags: vb.net, validation, dll

İ m tring to do a validation dll for may textbox. my dll's codes like this

```
    Public Class validatedll
    Function onlynumbers(ByVal r As String)
        Dim list As String, character As String
        Dim i As Integer
        list = "1234567890"
        i = 1
        If r <> "" Then
cntinue:
            If i > 10 Then
                MsgBox("invalid character. Last character will be delete !")
                r = Mid(r, 1, Len(r) - 1)
                Return r
                Exit Function
            End If
            character = Mid(list, i, 1)
            If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(r, 1) = character Then Exit Function
            i = i + 1
            GoTo cntinue
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

And i m useing this dll in my project like this

```
Imports ModifiedTextbox
Public Class Form1
    Public validate As New validatedll
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        ' TextBox1.Text = validate.onlynumbers(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = validate.onlynumbers(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

My problem is, if i use this dll in TextBox1_TextChanged event, Textbox1's text showing to me nothing because dll is not returning numbers. İf i use this code with button, code is working and deleting last character if a letter.

How can i use this dll in textchanged event? pls help to me.
My best regards

Comment: setting .Text in the textchanged event will fire another TextChanged event.  Why do you need to get involved with the user's every keystroke?  The TextBox has perfectly good Validation events for that, or use a MaskedEdit control to set a mask that only accepts numerals in whatever pattern you need.

Comment: Ty for you comment. i need to allow chars what i want. for example "only numbers and /" or "only uppercase and some lowercase chars"

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your weren't getting a return is whenever your loop found the right character it exited.

A few things:

A function should always have an As clause to specify the return type.  You may remember the return today what about a year from now?

Never use `GoTo`.  VB.net has several functional loops that will do pretty whatever you like.

Assuming that you want to extend this to support other validations you might want to consider another approach:

```
Public Class validatedll
    Sub onlynumbers(tb As TextBox)
        While Not tb.Text = "" AndAlso Not Double.TryParse(tb.Text, vbNull)
            tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(tb.Text.Length - 1)
            tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

I made it a sub that gets passed a reference to the textbox.  This keeps the mechanism of your validation more compartmentalized.  This will also make it easier if you decide to extend this class to be a custom control.

This tests if the string is a number, and keeps subtracting characters until it's empty or is a number.  This will work for on the fly validation or on exit validation.

Comment: Ty for you comment. i need to allow chars what i want. for example "only numbers and / and ." or "only uppercase and some lowercase chars" bla bla

Comment: (tb As TextBox) didnt worked in class project. But i tried in form project its worked because form has TextBox control.

Comment: You can import the Form library to the class.  Using Double.TryParse will allow any number characters and the decimal character.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve my problem. Maybe somebody needs that. You can add which chars to wanna allow with orelse;

```
Function onlynumbers(ByVal chars As String, ByVal exclmtn As Boolean, Optional title As String = "Title what you want")
    If chars = "" Then Exit Function
    If _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(chars, 1) = "1" OrElse _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(chars, 1) = "2" OrElse _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(chars, 1) = "3" OrElse _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(chars, 1) = "4" OrElse _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(chars, 1) = "5" OrElse _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(chars, 1) = "6" OrElse _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(chars, 1) = "7" OrElse _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(chars, 1) = "8" OrElse _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(chars, 1) = "9" OrElse _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(chars, 1) = "0" Then
        Return chars
        Exit Function
    Else
        If exclmtn = False Then
            chars = Mid(chars, 1, Len(chars) - 1)
            Return chars
            Exit Function
        End If
        If exclmtn = True Then
            MsgBox("invalid. last char ll delete !", , title)
            chars = Mid(chars, 1, Len(chars) - 1)
            Return chars
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
End Function
```